# SQL query to group by integer value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to do an SQL query to count the total numbers of rows that contain each integer in a 'metric' column.

I.e. my data looks like:

```
RowName | Metric
Row 1   | 3
Row 2   | 3
Row 3   | 6
Row 4   | 6
```

And I want to find how many rows have a 'metric' value of 3, and how many have a value of 6:

```
Metric | Count
6      | 2
3      | 2
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(Metric) FROM tablename GROUP BY Metric
```

But that returns an error. I know this is really simple and probably been answered many times before. As I am new to SQL I have tried searching, but probably don't quite know what I am searching for.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I didn't catch the error. But surely if it is wrong, it will be obvious to anyone that knows SQL (which is probably a requirement of being able to answer the question) what is wrong with the query.

Comment: Nope, not obvious by any means "to anyone that knows SQL". Run the query again and post the detailed error.

Comment: So I take it you have no idea if the syntax in the above question looks correct or not. No need to be rude about it; if you don't want to answer the question, just move on.

Comment: Run the query again and show us the error!

Comment: No need. Two other people have given valid answers. Maybe spend more time helping people learn rather than shooting them down because they didn't ask in the exact way you 'expect'. I could have just left out the part about it returning an error, and I doubt I would have got the same response. I could have just asked it in a hypothetical way. Thanks for the down-votes on a perfectly valid; straightforward, syntax related question. Standard stack overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT Metric, COUNT(Metric) `Count`
FROM `project.dataset.your_table` 
GROUP BY Metric
```

Answer (score 0):

[See it in action here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/23d13/3/0)

```
SELECT metric, [count]=COUNT(*) 
FROM tablename
GROUP BY Metric
```